# Implement a simple echo server using asyncio

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I am trying to implement a simple echo server using asyncio. Here's my attempt:

```
import asyncio

async def process(reader, writer):
    while True:
        data = await reader.readline()
        writer.write(data)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
listener = asyncio.start_server(process, host=None, port=2500)
loop.run_until_complete(listener)
loop.run_forever()
```

This starts the server and I can connect from multiple clients, also the clients have their messages echoed back to them. The problem is when I close one of the clients, the echo messages stop appearing on the other connected clients too. Why does that happen and how can I prevent that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server hangs because the loop is not exited when a connection is closed. The convention is when a network read function returns no data, it means EOF. The server must handle it, e.g.:

```
while True:
    data = await reader.readline()
    if not data:
        break
    writer.write(data)
```

Without the break the loop is executed again and again, because the EOF state will not change.

Please note that each connection is handled by its own `process` which is called with a reader and a writer belonging to that connection.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it. I have that piece of code in all my networking code, doing asyncio for the first time I just forgot about it.